# Вывести строку из символов В и G,

Tags: python

задача такая, вводятся два числа условно x и y, x =B, а y = G, строка длины x+y , надо вывести (любую) строку, в которой рядом с B стоит G и наоборот с G стоит B. Если так расставить символы не удаётся, вывести строку NO SOLUTION
Например:
Входные данные

5 5

Выходные данные

BGBGBGBGBG

Входные данные

5 3

Выходные данные

BGBGBBGB

Входные данные

100 1

Выходные данные

NO SOLUTION

```
from itertools import product
x,y = map (int,input().split())
c = x+y
if x/y > 2:
    print('NO SOLUTION')
    
for i in product('BG',repeat = c):
    s = ''.join(i)
    if (s[0]!=s[1] and s[-1]!=s[-2]) and (not 'BBB' in s and not 'GGG' in s):
        print(s)
        break
```

Проблема в том, что при вводе x и y >10, программа выполняется слишком долго, максимальное значение x и y может быть равно 100 ,проблема в том, как ускорить процесс перебора в itertools для большого количества символов x и y ?

Answer (score 2):

Такая функция должна подойти:

```
def create_string(x, y):
    swapped = False
    if x < y:
        x, y, swapped = y, x, True
    
    # варианты, когда нельзя собрать строку    
    if x==0 or y==0 or x>y*2: 
        return 'NO SOLUTION'
    if x==y: # если x и y равны, то ответ - просто чередуем буквы
        return 'BG'*x
    # общий вид строки : b gbb gbb gbb ... gb        
    string  = ('b' + 'gbb'*(y-1) + 'gb')
    # здесь мы убираем лишние буквы 'b' из "общего вида" строки
    string = string.replace('gbb', 'gb', string.count('b')-x)
    
    # если мы меняли x и y местами, то буквы g и b тоже надо поменять в ответе
    if swapped:
        return string.replace('g', 'B').replace('b', 'G')    
    return string.replace('g', 'G').replace('b', 'B')
```

---

Спасибо [@MBo](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/291659/mbo) за [идею](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1488804/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%92-%D0%B8-g/1488832?noredirect=1#comment2668201_1488832) перейти от генерации+замены к чистой генерации.

```
def create_string(x, y):
    swapped = False
    if x < y:
        x, y, swapped = y, x, True
    
    # варианты, когда нельзя собрать строку    
    if x==0 or y==0 or x>y*2: 
        return 'NO SOLUTION'
    if x==y: # если x и y равны, то ответ - просто чередуем буквы
        return 'BG'*x
    string  = 'b' + 'gbb'*(x-y-1) + 'gb'*(2*y-x+1)
    # если мы меняли x и y местами, то буквы g и b тоже надо поменять в ответе
    if swapped:
        return string.replace('g', 'B').replace('b', 'G')    
    return string.replace('g', 'G').replace('b', 'B')
```

Comment: Спасибо, это работает, но не очень понятно как,не могли бы вы в общем написать как это работает?

Comment: @nikitadvu добавил комментарии в код, лучше уже не знаю как объяснить.  *общий вид* строки я увидел, когда записывал варианты строк своим глазом

Comment: А может быть, не убирать лишние буквы, а сразу объединить нужное количество gbb и gb?

Comment: @MBo вариант интересный, но надо сесть немного посчитать :)

Comment: n1tr0xs как мне кажется, `(y-x)*'gbb'+(2*x-y)*'gb'`

Comment: @MBo пока выяснил, что `'gbb'*(x-y-1)`, но дальше что-то в ступоре :(

Comment: Если я правильно посчитал, то ваши префикс и суффикс не нужны - `(y-x)*'gbb'+(2*x-y)*'gb'` даёт ровно y штук b и x штук g, в том числе и в случае x==y

Comment: @MBo `y-x` всегда даст отрицательное число в моей функции (кроме `x==y`). пробовал убрать *swap*, но не помогло. не проходит решение

Comment: @n1tr0xs Ох, я подумал, что у вас y>x, тогда их надо поменять местами (x-y)*'gbb'+(2*y-x)*'gb'